# Polymer 1.0: How to nest functions?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to call an observer function `'_propChanged'` that, in turn, calls two others `_foo()` and  `_bar()` . How would I do that?

### Code

```
{
  is: 'x-el',
  properties: {
    prop: {
      type: String,
      notify: true,
      observer: '_propChanged'
    }
  },
  _propChanged: function() {
    _foo(); // This doesn't work
    _bar(); // This doesn't work
  },
  _foo: function() {
    // Do stuff
  },
  _bar: function() {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `this._foo()` and `this._bar()` inside your `_observePropChanges` function instead.

Comment: @miqid that should do it. Why don't you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply prefix your function calls with `this` for the names to resolve properly.

```
_observePropChanges: function () {
  this._foo();
  this._bar();
}
```